# Method wait() and notifyAll() is not static

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, producer-consumer, notify

```
public synchronized  static int get() {
    while(cheia()==false){
        try{
            wait();
          }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }

    if (fila[inicio] != 0) {
        int retornaValor = fila[inicio];
        fila[inicio] = 0;
        inicio++;
        if (inicio == size) {
            inicio = 0;
        }
        notifyAll();
        return retornaValor;
    }
    notifyAll();
    return 0;
}
```

Why the wait() and notifyAll() do no run in this code?

IDE says: the method wait() (or notifyAll) is not static?

Can you help me?

Comment: You could use `ClassName.class.wait()` and `ClassName.class.notifyAll()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

It is because you are within a static method, which means the method is executing on the class instance and not the object instance.  `wait` and `notify` are instance methods.

Create an object lock instead and use that to do the synchronization and signaling.

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public static int get(){
   synchronized(lock){
      lock.wait();
      lock.notify();
      ...etc
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

synchronized static method locks on the Class object, so naturally, you can do:

```
[youclass].class.wait();
[youclass].class.notify();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a non-static method such as `wait()` or `notifyAll()` from a static method. You cannot do this. Change your get method to this

```
public synchronized int get()
```

Comment: Most getters are instance-based, so static access is the best way to do this. Example: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`, `Desktop.getDesktop()`, `Runtime.getRuntime()`, etc.

Comment: You're right. But I am not sure if the OP wants to use his method in that way, or is he thinking of using it on an object. I assumed the latter.

Comment: public void run(){
        int value=0;
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
            value = CircularQueue.get();
            System.out.println("Consumer #"+i+"got "+value);
        }
    }

but this code gets a warning like this: the CircularQueue.get() method is not static

(sorry, but i dont now how to edit the code example)

Answer (score -1):

What do you expect it to `wait` for? You have to wait for some specific object to be notified and there's no object here.

Comment: he waits to get a variable with this method

<pre> <code>public void run(){
        int value=0;
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
            value = CircularQueue.get();
            System.out.println("Consumer #"+i+"got "+value);
        }
    }